# The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble understanding the error why the ".docs" part in the line
"final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;" throws the error. I get that it has a chance to return a null value but why? And how do I solve this error?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chatapp/widgets/chat/message_bubble.dart';

class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final uid = user?.uid;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future<User>.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),
        builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
          if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('chat')
                  .orderBy(
                    'createdAt',
                    descending: true,
                  )
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
                final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
                return ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: chatDocs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => MessageBubble(
                    chatDocs[index]['text'],
                    chatDocs[index]['userId'] == uid,
                  ),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```

I've tried adding null checks and/or '?' to the parts where the compiler suggested I add them. Doing so resolves that error but it would now result into this error.

> Exception caught by widgets library
> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Which prevents the app from rendering the message bubbles resulting in a red textless background. I'm trying to have the code show chat bubbles which their positions are determined by the userId, with the current user on the right and other users at the left of the screen.

Update: I've narrowed down the problem to the line that contains "chatDocs[index]['userId'] == uid". App works fine if I comment this out, replace it with either a true or false value and add the needed null checks as the message bubble widget takes two values which are a String and a bool. Still have no idea why that particular line of code is the one causing the errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the program should've been looking for the field 'userID' instead of 'userId'. Always triple check your database fields.